# Make an overlay on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a trouble with an effect I want to achieve.

When I put the mouse over this element :

```html
<div class="process">
  <h3 class="text-center">Process</h3>
  <ul class="row text-center list-inline  wowload bounceInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: bounceInUp;">
    <li data-id="Reflexion">
      <span><i class="fa fa-flask"></i><b>Reflexion</b></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to have an overlay over all the page and over this overlay my `<ul>...</ul>`

I have tried with `z-index` and `position` but it doesn't work, my overlay is always over all the page and over the `<ul>...</ul>`

Here is the style of `<ul></ul>` and `.overlay`

```
.process ul li{
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    border: 1px solid #CEEBF0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 1.25em;
    line-height: 13.5em;
    color: #21ABCA;
     -webkit-transition: border-color 0.5s ease-in; /* Safari */
     -moz-transition: border-color 0.5s ease-in; /* Firefox */
    transition: border-color 0.5s ease-in;
}
.process ul li span{line-height: 2em;display: inline-block;font-weight: 300;}
.process ul li span i{font-size: 3em;}
.process ul li span b{display: block;font-size: 1em;font-weight: 300;}

.process ul li:hover {
    border-color:#3498db;
    background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219,1.0);
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Here is the script I'm using to listen mouse event :

```
$(".process ul li").on({
    mouseenter : function() {
        $('#overlay').addClass('overlay');
    },
    mouseleave : function() {
        $('#overlay').removeClass('overlay');
    },
});
```

---

**Update**

**There is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4th6u9jx/1/) that show better than words my trouble**

Comment: You didn't include the class `over1` in the CSS snippet you provided...

Comment: could not find `process ` class

Comment: I usually use `position: absolute` for overlays. You've tried this and it doesn't work?

Comment: Show full DOM, not only `<ul>` snippet

Comment: I've edited my question, sorry for that

Comment: @wilson Make sure your `.overlay` DOM Element has both the class and the id. Since in your CSS you use the **class** `overlay` and in your JS you use the **id** `overlay`. Here's [what I have as of now](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/ygpkmzpw/)

Comment: @JeffNoel yeah it's ok, the code is the same as here and no trouble for this point

Comment: I make a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4th6u9jx/1/) to see better the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I make overlays I usually use absolute positioning to get it right. Without knowing what effect you want specifically, here's a generic demo of how an overlay might work.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxaLvL46/1/)

By setting the overlay's position to `absolute`, and all of its positional attributes to 0, it covers the box it's bound to completely without having to worry about setting widths or heights.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

I know you've solved the issue, but for those who may look later, here's a link to a fiddle wherein the issue has been solved.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4th6u9jx/4/)

Comment: Thx man, but not the problem here, see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4th6u9jx/1/) if you want to see my trouble

Comment: @wilson I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4th6u9jx/4/)...is that what you needed?

Comment: Awesome ! the @Jacque Goupil answer was not the good finally. It was exactly what i want but my english is so bad and i guess my explanation was very unclear

Answer (score 0):

The Z-index property only works when both elements are positioned manually. Make sure the list has `position: relative` or `position: absolute` too, not just the overlay. Then you need to give a **higer value** to the z-index of the list.

EDIT: try adding this to your code:

```
.process {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

You'll have to actually play with Z-index to make sure only the hovered panel is in front of the overlay if that's what you want, but this proves that you need to set a position attribute on what you want to be manually z-positioned.

Comment: You're only setting the z-index on one thing. Pretty much everything I mention is not in your code. That won't work.

Comment: thanx this solved my problem ! What a noob error ... But now it's work, i can't vote today because i reach the limit but tomorrow i vote up

Comment: Your last edit is working, but i want to not overlay all my `.process` div, the `<li></li>` element who has the "over" state should be over all the other element